# amp goback button to navigate to pervious page

Tags: amp-html

I have a goback button in an AMP project. How can I make it to get to pervious page. What I want is to navigate back in history basically.

```
on="tap:goback"???
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this I am not sure it is work or not : on="tap:AMP.goBack"
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-actions-and-events

Answer (score 0):

The `AMP` target implements top-level actions that apply to the whole document, which includes `goBack`, for example:

```
<button on="tap:AMP.goBack">Back</button>
```

However, this only applies to the history within the document (e.g. opening a lightbox or undoing `AMP.pushState`). Going back to the previous page on a browser level is not currently supported, but the feature is requested and discussed in [#5225](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/5225).

Comment: I added information to clarify, this doesn't go back on a browser level.